# importing variable column excel sheets to mysql using java

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, apache-poi

I am using apache poi to read the data from excel to mysql table. And i had did it for excel sheet with 2 fields. my code is like,

```
try
        {
            fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);


        //creating workbook, sheet(from poi jar file)
        HSSFWorkbook workBook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
        HSSFSheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);
        //Iterator for iterating rows in sheet
        Iterator itr = sheet.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {

            HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) itr.next();
            Iterator cell = row.cellIterator();
            List data = new ArrayList();
            while(cell.hasNext())
            {
                HSSFCell value = (HSSFCell) cell.next();                    
                if (value.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) 
                {
                    data.add(value.getNumericCellValue());
                }
                else if (value.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN) 
                {
                    data.add(value.getBooleanCellValue());
                }
                else if (value.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
                {
                    data.add(value.getStringCellValue());
                }
            }
            sheetData.add(data);

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
```

And the put the data on an arraylist. ten inserted it to database.. But 
now i need the system to get the excel files with variale number of cloumns. Can i achiece it? I just need some help badly. So plz help me with some ideas and possibly with some codes.

thanks in advance.
sujith

Comment: does these excel files totally unknown by your application, or, does your application stored column informations of some excels in somewhere?

Comment: my application puts the data to a table of 15 columns. But my excel sheets columns may vary between 2-15

Answer (score 0):

When iterating a single row

```
if (value.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC){
                     data.add(value.getNumericCellValue());                 
}
```

you can add a new if block which checks for

```
if(value.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK){
break;
}
```

Here i am assuming that all the data in your columns will be simultaneous (1 2 3 4 blank) and not like this (1 blank blank 2 3 4 5). So the moment you get the blank type your iterator will shift to next row.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the first row of excel sheet to store column names of mysql table, so you will have a **column-index - column-name** mapping information.

Then, when insert to mysql table, you can choose column names in the first row to operate. For example

**Excel 1**

```
   =========================
   | A      | B      | C
===+========+========+======
1  | name   | gender | age   <-- column name row
---+--------+--------+------
2  | josh   | male   | 28
---+--------+--------+------
3  | linda  | female | 22
----------------------------
```

**SQL 1**

```
INSERT INTO table (name, gender, age) VALUES ('josh', 'male', 28),('linda', 'female', 22)
```

**Excel 2**

```
   ==================
   | A      | B 
===+========+========
1  | name   | country <-- column name row
---+--------+--------
2  | 张三   | China
---+--------+--------
3  | emily  | USA
---------------------
```

**SQL 2**

```
INSERT INTO table (name, country) VALUES ('张三', 'China'),('emily', 'USA')
```

Answer (score 0):

We Can Also Use Simple And Best Way 2 Upload An Excel Sheet Into Database

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="./ExcelSample" method="post" id="formdata"
    enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return excelUpload('Conform')">
<label for="inputSuccess2" class="control-label">
<div id="scn">Select Excel File</div>
</label> <input type="file" name="excel" id="excelfile"
    class="form-control active"> <label class="control-label">&nbsp;</label>
<input type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-orange" id="Upload"
    value="Upload"></form>
</body>
</html>

package com.excel.Sample.ExcelAnn;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(value=ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface ExcelColumn {
    boolean ignore() default false;
    String label() default "";
}

package com.excel.Sample.ExcelAnn;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(value=ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface ExcelReport {
    String reportName();
}


    package com.excel.Sample.Actions;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;

import com.excel.Sample.ExcelAnn.ExcelColumn;
import com.excel.Sample.ExcelAnn.ExcelReport;

public class ExcelAction {
    private HSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
    private String workbookName = "Book1.xls";
    private Map<String, String> fieldLabelMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private List<String> orderLabels = new ArrayList<String>();
    private CellStyle columnHeaderCellStyle = null;

    public ExcelAction() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        setWorkbook(new HSSFWorkbook());
        setColumnHeaderCellStyle(createColumnHeaderCellStyle());
    }

    private CellStyle createColumnHeaderCellStyle() {
        CellStyle cellStyle = getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
        cellStyle.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        cellStyle.setFillBackgroundColor(new HSSFColor.GREY_25_PERCENT()
                .getIndex());
        cellStyle.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        cellStyle.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        cellStyle.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        cellStyle.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        return cellStyle;
    }

    public void closeWorksheet() {
        FileOutputStream fileOut;
        try {
            fileOut = new FileOutputStream(getWorkbookName());
            getWorkbook().write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private HSSFSheet getSheetWithName(String name) {
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(name);
        return sheet;
    }

    private void initializeForRead(InputStream inp) throws IOException {
        workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inp);
    }

    private <T> void processAnnotations(T object) {
        Class<?> clazz = object.getClass();
        ExcelReport reportAnnotation = (ExcelReport) clazz
                .getAnnotation(ExcelReport.class);


        for (Method method : clazz.getMethods()) {

            ExcelColumn excelColumn = method.getAnnotation(ExcelColumn.class);
            if ((excelColumn != null) && !excelColumn.ignore()) {
                getFieldLabelMap().put(excelColumn.label(), method.getName());
                getOrderLabels().add(excelColumn.label());
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> List<T> readData(String classname, InputStream inp)
            throws Exception {
        Class clazz = Class.forName(classname);
        processAnnotations(clazz.newInstance());
        initializeForRead(inp);
        HSSFSheet sheet = getSheetWithName("Sheet1");
        List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
        Map<String, String> mp = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();
        int rowCount = 0;
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            T one = (T) clazz.newInstance();
            try {
                int colCount = 0;
                result.add(one);
                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    if (rowCount == 0) {
                        mp.put(colCount + "", cell.getStringCellValue()
                                .toString().trim());

                    } else {
                        int type = cell.getCellType();
                        String labelName = mp.get(colCount + "");
                        String getter = getFieldLabelMap().get(labelName);
                        String fieldName = getter.substring(3);
                        fieldName = decapitalize(fieldName);
                        Method method = constructMethod(clazz, fieldName);
                        if (type == 1) {
                            String value = cell.getStringCellValue();
                            Object[] values = new Object[1];
                            values[0] = value;
                            method.invoke(one, values);
                        } else if (type == 0) {
                            Double num = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                            Class<?> returnType = getGetterReturnClass(clazz,
                                    fieldName);
                            if (returnType == Integer.class) {
                                method.invoke(one,(Integer) num.intValue());
                            } else if (returnType == Double.class) {
                                method.invoke(one, (Integer) num.intValue());
                            } else if (returnType == Float.class) {
                                method.invoke(one, num.floatValue());
                            } else if (returnType == Date.class) {
                                method.invoke(one, cell.getDateCellValue());
                            }
                        } else if (type == 3) {
                            double num = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                            Object[] values = new Object[1];
                            values[0] = num;
                            method.invoke(one, values);
                        }
                    }
                    colCount++;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            rowCount++;
        }
        return result;
    }

    private Class<?> getGetterReturnClass(Class<?> clazz, String fieldName) {
        String methodName = "get" + capitalize(fieldName);
        Class<?> returnType = null;
        for (Method method : clazz.getMethods()) {
            if (method.getName().equals(methodName)) {
                returnType = method.getReturnType();
                break;
            }
        }
        return returnType;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private Method constructMethod(Class clazz, String fieldName)
            throws SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException {
        Class<?> fieldClass = getGetterReturnClass(clazz, fieldName);
        return clazz.getMethod("set" + capitalize(fieldName), fieldClass);
    }

    public <T> void writeReportToExcel(List<T> data) throws Exception {
        processAnnotations(data.get(0));
        Sheet sheet = getWorkbook().createSheet(
                data.get(0).getClass().getName());
        int rowCount = 0;
        int columnCount = 0;
        Row row = sheet.createRow(rowCount++);
        for (String labelName : getOrderLabels()) {
            Cell cel = row.createCell(columnCount++);
            cel.setCellValue(labelName);
            cel.setCellStyle(getColumnHeaderCellStyle());
        }
        Class<? extends Object> classz = data.get(0).getClass();
        for (T t : data) {
            row = sheet.createRow(rowCount++);

            columnCount = 0;

            for (String label : getOrderLabels()) {
                String methodName = getFieldLabelMap().get(label);
                Cell cel = row.createCell(columnCount);
                Method method = classz.getMethod(methodName);
                Object value = method.invoke(t, (Object[]) null);
                if (value != null) {
                    if (value instanceof String) {
                        cel.setCellValue((String) value);
                    } else if (value instanceof Long) {
                        cel.setCellValue((Long) value);
                    } else if (value instanceof Integer) {
                        cel.setCellValue((Integer) value);
                    } else if (value instanceof Double) {
                        cel.setCellValue((Double) value);
                    }
                }
                columnCount++;
            }
        }
    }

    public Map<String, String> getFieldLabelMap() {
        return fieldLabelMap;
    }

    public void setFieldLabelMap(Map<String, String> fieldLabelMap) {
        this.fieldLabelMap = fieldLabelMap;
    }

    public List<String> getOrderLabels() {
        return orderLabels;
    }

    public void setOrderLabels(List<String> orderLabels) {
        this.orderLabels = orderLabels;
    }

    public String capitalize(String string) {
        String capital = string.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
        return capital + string.substring(1);
    }

    public String decapitalize(String string) {
        String capital = string.substring(0, 1).toLowerCase();
        return capital + string.substring(1);
    }

    public String getWorkbookName() {
        return workbookName;
    }

    public void setWorkbookName(String workbookName) {
        this.workbookName = workbookName;
    }

    void setWorkbook(HSSFWorkbook workbook) {
        this.workbook = workbook;
    }

    Workbook getWorkbook() {
        return workbook;
    }

    public CellStyle getColumnHeaderCellStyle() {
        return columnHeaderCellStyle;
    }

    public void setColumnHeaderCellStyle(CellStyle columnHeaderCellStyle) {
        this.columnHeaderCellStyle = columnHeaderCellStyle;
    }

}


package com.excel.Sample.Model;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.excel.Sample.ExcelAnn.ExcelColumn;

@Entity
@Table(name = "directory")
public class Directory {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "Test_Name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "Path", nullable = false)
    private String path;
    @Column(name = "Directory", nullable = false)
    private String directory;
    @Column(name = "ContainedFiles", nullable = false)
    private Integer containedFiles;

    @Column(name = "DateFormate", nullable = false)
    private Date dateFormate;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ExcelColumn(label = "Test Name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @ExcelColumn(label = "Path")
    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    @ExcelColumn(label = "Directory")
    public String getDirectory() {
        return directory;
    }

    public void setDirectory(String directory) {
        this.directory = directory;
    }

    @ExcelColumn(label = "ContainedFiles")
    public Integer getContainedFiles() {
        return containedFiles;
    }

    public void setContainedFiles(Integer containedFiles) {
        this.containedFiles = containedFiles;
    }

    @ExcelColumn(label = "DateFormate")
    public Date getDateFormate() {
        return dateFormate;
    }

    public void setDateFormate(Date dateFormate) {
        this.dateFormate = dateFormate;
    }
}

package com.excel.Sample.Servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import com.excel.Sample.Actions.ExcelAction;
import com.excel.Sample.Model.Directory;
import com.excel.util.HibernateUtil;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ExcelSample
 */
public class ExcelSample extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static String modelName = "com.excel.Sample.Model.Directory";

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public ExcelSample() {
        super();

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {

            boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
            if (!isMultipart) {
            } else {
                FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
                ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
                List items = null;
                try {
                    items = upload.parseRequest(request);
                } catch (FileUploadException e) {
                    e.getMessage();
                }
                FileItem item = (FileItem) items.get(0);
                try {
                    ExcelAction ea = new ExcelAction();
                    List<Directory> e = ea.readData(modelName, item
                            .getInputStream());
                    out.println("<table>");
                    for (int i = 1; i < e.size(); i++) {
                        Directory ex = (Directory) e.get(i);
                        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory()
                                .openSession();
                        Transaction transaction = null;

                        try {
                            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
                            session.save(ex);
                            transaction.commit();
                        } catch (HibernateException exp) {
                            transaction.rollback();
                            exp.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {
                            session.close();
                        }
                        String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
                                .format(ex.getDateFormate());
                        out.println("<tr><td>" + ex.getContainedFiles()
                                + " </td><td> " + ex.getDirectory()
                                + " </td><td> " + ex.getPath() + " </td><td> "
                                + ex.getName() + "</td><td> " + date
                                + "</td></tr>");
                    }
                    out.println("</table>");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }

}
```

1. Excel For Mate Is As Follows

> Test Name Path    Directory   ContainedFiles  DateFormate
>   .settings /home/david/dev/workspaces/Dec2009/ExcelAnnotationReport/.settings  directory   1   5/2/2013
>   src   /home/david/dev/workspaces/Dec2009/ExcelAnnotationReport/src    directory   1   12/3/2013
>   .classpath1   /home/david/dev/workspaces/Dec2009/ExcelAnnotationReport/.classpath1    file1   1   11/4/2013
>   test  /home/david/dev/workspaces/Dec2009/ExcelAnnotationReport/test   directory   1   3/5/2013
>   test.xls  /home/david/dev/workspaces/Dec2009/ExcelAnnotationReport/test.xls   file    11  6/6/2013
>   .project  /home/david/dev/workspaces/Dec2009/ExcelAnnotationReport/.project   file    1   12/7/2013
>   bin   /home/david/dev/workspaces/Dec2009/ExcelAnnotationReport/bin    directory   1   6/8/2013

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: Use The Above Link For Downloading The Above Code. If U See This Code You  May Get Clear View About The Code. And This Is based On Reflections and Used Own Annotations.